# Apply css only on the wrapped part of text

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML component that has an image floating to the left and text on the right. When the text's height is larger than the image, the text will wrap to the left. I want to add some padding between the image and the wrapped text. I could add a bottom padding to the image, but I don't want the padding to show up when the text is not wrapped. Here is what the component should look like when the text is no wrapped. The image should not have a bottom padding:

[image]

Here is what it should look like when the text is wrapped. There should be some padding between the image and the wrapped text:

[image]
Is there a way to do this through css?

Comment: You loose the height when you're floating an element, so it would never fill up the parent element with a border, but overflow outside of it.

Answer (score 2):

An idea in case the image height is fixed or known:

```css
.container {
  border:2px solid;
  min-height:200px; /* same as image height */
  font-size:19px;
}

.container img {
  float:left;
  margin:0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1014/200/200" > Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque fermentum quis mi vitae molestie. Sed scelerisque fringilla interdum. Duis ac purus nisl. Nulla vehicula vehicula turpis id convallis. Etiam nec nisl nibh. Mauris lorem mauris, vehicula nec massa in, accumsan egestas eros. Integer vehicula nulla sed enim laoreet maximus. Vestibulum at interdum sem. Sed interdum volutpat massa,
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it. Follow this example for HTML and css.

```css
body { 
            margin: 20px; 
            text-align: center; 
        } 
        img { 
            float: left; 
            margin: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
        } 
        p { 
            text-align: justify; 
            font-size: 20px; 
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> 
        Wraping an Image with the text 
    </title> 
</head> 

<body> 
    
    <div class="square"> 
        <div> 
            <img src= "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1024px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" alt="Longtail boat in Thailand" width="300px"> 
        </div> 
        
        <p> 
            How many times were you frustrated while looking 
            out for a good collection of programming/algorithm 
            /interview questions? What did you expect and what 
            did you get? This portal has been created to 
            provide well written, well thought and well 
            explained solutions for selected questions. 
            An IIT Roorkee alumnus and founder of GeeksforGeeks. 
            He loves to solve programming problems in most 
            efficient ways. Apart from GeeksforGeeks, he has 
            worked with DE Shaw and Co. as a software developer 
            and JIIT Noida as an assistant professor. It is a 
            good platform to learn programming. It is an 
            educational website. Prepare for the Recruitment 
            drive of product based companies like Microsoft, 
            Amazon, Adobe etc with a free online placement 
            preparation course. 
        </p> 
    </div> 
</body> 

</html>
```